# Does my name on my checks have to match my drivers license.

Tags: banking

My middle name is Ann. I want my checks to say P.A.Myers
The bank says they should say “Patricia Piper Myers”.
Piper is my maiden name.

Comment: Is your maiden name on your drivers license?

Comment: If your ID shows your full name and the checks say P.A., I wouldn't expect a problem with them at all. I use a shorted form of my first name on my checks and my id has the long version and nobody has ever complained.

Comment: Worth noting also that you do not necessarily need to go through your bank to get checks printed for your account, and it may even be less expensive to go through a (reputable) third party printer.

Comment: @yoozer8 My bank rejects any self-made checks (not sure how; presumably some sort of serial number or rejecting ones not with their look/feel) so that's not necessarily a usable approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can have checks printed that say whatever name you want.

If you want them *accepted*, the closer the name on the checks matches the name on your id, the better.

Comment: This. My checkbooks all have different addresses and I don't know if any of them match the address on my driver license...

Comment: In short anyone you want to give a check to can decline to accept it as payment for any or no reason at all. Your only option is to minimize the reasons.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the name on your *account* instead of on your *id*? Maybe they're the same but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

The recipients of your checks typically have no idea what your ID says nor should they care what you call yourself. I have checks that just have my last name with no address and that has never caused an issue. If you are paying by check in person the recipient could ask for ID and may hassle you about the mis-match, but I'm skeptical that would be much of an issue these days, I've not been asked for ID when paying by check in years.

When you are the recipient of a check, it's best if the check is made out to your name as it appears on a form of ID, since confirming the check is intended for you is part of the check cashing/deposit process.

Comment: Would love an explanation for the downvote.